# Only bind certain properties of BindingList to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Some background:

```
public class Base
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : Base
{
    public string E { get; set; }
    public List<string> F { get; set; }
    public List<string> G { get; set; }
    public Image H { get; set; }
}
```

The Base class is used as a base for several other classes which all have common properties. The derived classes add on properties specific to that derived class.

In my View I have a DataGrid bound to my `DerivedClassViewModel`'s `BindingList<DerivedClass>`:

```
<DataGrid Margin="318,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding BindingList}">
```

This works nicely, I can add and remove items from the BindingList and the DataGrid automatically updates to reflect this. However, `DerivedClass` has several properties (the `List<string> F/H` for example) that I don't want to be displayed in the DataGrid. **How do I bind only certain properties of DerivedClass to the DataGrid while still using `BindingList<DerivedClass>`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to disable AutoGenerateColumns on the DataGrid and define the columns explicitly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columns(v=vs.100).aspx, or use the AutoGeneratingColumn event to discard columns you don't want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but I guess it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

@see [BindingList(IList)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) (second item under "Constructors")

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me since I would have to specify a new type which contains only the properties of `DerivedClass` that I want.